What is the current status of the Zephyr Venus rover research?
The Zephyr Venus rover is a proposed NASA Discovery proposal that is/was being investigated by Nasa's Glenn Research Centre, with an intended launch date of 2039.  However I couldn't find any information about it after 2019.  Has it been closed down or is there still ongoing research?

research at least related to a rover on Venus: Would it be possible to build a probe that could operate at about 480 °C (900F degrees) without insulation? and Venus probe with refrigerated electronics powered by an RTG (more like the Mars rovers) and Vacuum tube microchips for Venus probe; feasibility and challenges? and Mechanical computing hardware for a future Venusian rover? How does it work?

and Potential high temperature power sources for a Venus lander

From Wikipedia:

When the most critical hardware becomes available and is tested, Landis intends to propose the mission to NASA's Discovery program to compete for funding and a launch intended for 2039.

Personally, this seems unlikely to me as a plausible launch date - DAVINCI and VERITAS were both selected for the most recent Discovery mission cycle, and they have already been delayed by multiple years (NET 2031). Also, a lot of the technology involved was apparently related to research on the Venera-D mission collaborating with Russia, which for political reasons is off the table.
EDIT: Didn't fully read the question. So to clarify, there has most likely been no apparent progress because NASA does not currently have enough budget. The two missions I mentioned were both delayed due to Mars Sample Return eating a lot of the planetary science budget and the associated personnel cuts.
